# Why is Vue-Router not pushing to another component

Tags: api, vue.js, vuejs2, routes, vue-router

I'm trying to access another page after i search for something in my search bar, but when i press enter nothing happens.

I already tried many different ways to access the DisplayBooks page after i searched for a books, but it only shows the DisplayBooks component in the url and the book data in the console.

Main.vue

```
<template>
    <v-container>
      <v-row class="text-center mt-10"> 
        <v-col class="mb-4" >
          <h3 class="display-2 font-weight-bold mb-3">
            Your mobile library
          </h3>
          <p class="subheading font-weight-regular">
            <v-text-field v-model="query" @keyup.enter="search" label="Search"></v-text-field>
          </p>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </template>
  <style scoped>
 
  </style>
  <script>
  import axios from 'axios';
  import router from '/router';

    export default {  
      data() {
    return {
      query: ''
    }
  },
  methods: {
    async search() {
      const url = `https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=${this.query}`;
      const response = await axios.get(url);
      const books = response.data.items;
      console.log(books)
      router.push({
      path: '/displaybooks',
      name: 'displaybooks',
      props: { books: books }
    });
    }
  }
    }
  </script>
```

router.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import DisplayBooks from '@/components/DisplayBooks.vue'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/displaybooks',
      name: 'displaybooks',
      component: DisplayBooks,
      props: true
    }
  ]
})
```

Main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import router from '/router'


Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  vuetify,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```